# LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'clang_rt.asan_dynamic_runtime_thunk-x86_64.lib'

Tags: c++, visual-c++, address-sanitizer

I'm trying to compile with the C++ address sanitizer (project property pages / C/C++ / Enable Address Sanitizer = YES), but I'm receiving the following error on compiling:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'clang_rt.asan_dynamic_runtime_thunk-x86_64.lib'
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to your project properties, and under **VC++ Directories** / Library Directories, add an entry:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\lib\x64
```

Make sure the directory exists! In particular, note the Visual Studio build number (14.29.30133) is being used in the path, so check if yours is different.

Comment: For VS 2022 the path was `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.34.31933\lib\x64`

Answer (score 1):

First you should make sure you installed the Address Sanitizer as described [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/addresssanitizer-asan-for-windows-with-msvc/)

Once you installed it, the library should be in your MSVC directory, it's different depending on the Visual Studio version you installed.

After you found the file, add it's folders path to the project Linker:

in Solution explorer Right click on

> ```
> Project > Properties > Linker > Additional Library Directories > Edit... > New line
> ```

Recompile, now the .lib file should be available if you compile with `/fsanitize=address` option.